# Rails - Apartment gem - Different schema for public and tenant database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, apartment-gem

I know by default Apartment will create same tables on both public and tenant database. And most of tables on public database are no use, empty tables. I also know that tenant database are depending on schema.rb

But I wonder if we can have different schema for public and tenant database? For example I have 5 tables: SignUp, Company, User , Task and Matter.

If I want the main database (public) only have SignUP,COmpany and User table, and tenants only have Task and Matter tables, is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 4):

Currently, this isn't possible with the apartment gem. This issue has been brought up a couple of times, see below.

[Apartment - Github issue](https://github.com/influitive/apartment/issues/230)

Comment: yes,i know that. Is their is any other options/gems available for doing this?

Comment: AFAIK, no.  I was looking to have a similar architecture as you describe above but ended up having a single schema.  I'm sure it's possible in some way although probably would involve rewriting a bunch of activerecord.